# Error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

Help, I can't build my release and I have no clue about this error. I have changed my `buildToolsVersion` version and tried same version for all dependencies but still I can't build my release. I am really new in react native.

**Here is the error log:**

```
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored not found.
C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\d52e557a57e5b369d784a4c8a2c12724\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.

C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\d52e557a57e5b369d784a4c8a2c12724\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.

C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\d52e557a57e5b369d784a4c8a2c12724\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:17:5-93: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.

C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\d52e557a57e5b369d784a4c8a2c12724\res\values\values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.

C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\d52e557a57e5b369d784a4c8a2c12724\res\values\values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/font not found.

C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\d52e557a57e5b369d784a4c8a2c12724\res\values\values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.

error: failed linking references.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-admob:verifyReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 11s
89 actionable tasks: 83 executed, 6 up-to-date
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

**app\build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.indogotv"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }   
    ...
}

...

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-admob')
    implementation project(':react-native-video-exoplayer')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been stuck with this error longer than I want to admit. Thank you.

Comment: try to add `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` into your dependencies in `app\build.gradle`.

Comment: @nawanTSL did you find any solutions ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52378246/5532513