# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name. 'ANDROID'

Tags: android

***every time I try to build I have this error shown: ***

> Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
>   Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
>   Error:(15, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Here is my build.gradle:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331411/errorresource-androidstyle-textappearance-material-widget-button-borderless-co)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check with updated compile and SDK version like.

```
compileSdkVersion 28 
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 28
```

And update all support dependency version to `28.0.0` instead `25.0.0`. Like this

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
```

Also update `compile` to `implementation`.

Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks  for replying ; thats exsactly what i have done  plus i have upgraded  my android studio version from 1.0.1 to  3.3.1  .